# How to use other language with tesseract on C# Tesseract 3.02 + Emgu 2.4.9

Tags: c#, tesseract

My 'tessdate' contain:
eng.traineddata, eng.cube.bigrams, eng.cube.fold, eng.cube.lm, eng.cube.nn, eng.cube.params
eng.cube.size, eng.cube.word-freq, eng.tesseract_cube.nn

rus.traineddata, rus.cube.fold, rus.cube.lm, rus.cube.nn, rus.cube.params, rus.cube.size, rus.cube.word-freq

I haven't got 'rus.cube.bigrams' and 'rus.tesseract_cube.nn' files in the tessdata dirrectory.

I fetch this mistake "Unable to create ocr model using Path 'tessdata' and language 'rus'", when I change 'eng' to 'rus' or 'ita' for example in this code:

> private Tesseract _ocr;
>
> ```
>   public LicensePlateDetector(String dataPath)
>   {
>      //create OCR engine
>       _ocr = new Tesseract("tessdata", "rus", Tesseract.OcrEngineMode.OEM_CUBE_ONLY);
>      _ocr.SetVariable("tessedit_char_whitelist", "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ-1234567890");
>   }
> ```

Where Am I mistaking?

Answer (score 1):

It says that it can't find rus language resources in tessdata folder. Check if you have set `Copy to Output Directory` for rus files to `Copy always`.
Also I've just tried to use [Tesseract .NET wrapper](https://github.com/charlesw/tesseract). It has more pleasent syntax:

```
using (var engine = new TesseractEngine(pathToLangFolder, "rus", EngineMode.Default))
{
    // have to load Pix via a bitmap since Pix doesn't support loading a stream.
    using (var image = new Bitmap(fileName))
    {
        using (var pix = PixConverter.ToPix(image))
        {
            using (var page = engine.Process(pix))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(page.GetMeanConfidence() + " : " + page.GetText());
            }
        }
    }
}
```